# MySQL : Insert Exactly Same Data Multiple Rows Without PHP Loop

Tags: php, mysql

I need to insert same data to my MySQL table without having PHP loop. The reason why I'm doing this is that because I have a column with Auto_Increment feature and that column associates with other table.

So, I just need to insert some *exactly same* data and it's multiple rows (dynamic) but by using single INSERT syntax below :

```
INSERT INTO outbox_multipart (TextDecoded) VALUES ('$SMSMessage')
```

how to have this single INSERT syntax, but produce n number of rows?

Comment: how to do it? example please..

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
INSERT INTO outbox_multipart (TextDecoded) VALUES ('$SMSMessage')
, ('$SMSMessage2'), ('$SMSMessage3'), ('$SMSMessage4');
```

Comment: `SMSMessage2` is a variable, not a string.

Comment: he mentioned its the same data i.e. a string in variable `$SMSMessage`

Comment: @coder1984 I agree with you, but the OP wasn't clear in this, he didn't say a variable. It was just the `$SMSMessage` in the statement he wrote. So I did what he asked fore which is `how to have this single INSERT syntax, but produce n number of rows`

Comment: if u dont consider it to be a variable, then you condsider it to be a string, which again would be `'$SMSMessage'`, `$` being considered as a char, as per his question. you changed it to `SMSMessage`

Comment: its just an observation, thats all :)

Comment: Take double quotes not single quotes for variable substitution - just FYI

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO outbox_multipart (TextDecoded) VALUES ('$SMSMessage'),('$SMSMessage')
,('$SMSMessage'),('$SMSMessage')
```

if done dynamically,

```
$n=5;
for ($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){$values.="('$SMSMessage'),";}
$values=substr($values,0,-1);
```

And the SQL be:

```
INSERT INTO outbox_multipart (TextDecoded) VALUES $values
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
     $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO outbox_multipart (TextDecoded) VALUES ('$SMSMessage')
      , ('$SMSMessage'),('$SMSMessage'),('$SMSMessage')");
```

Also, just so you know, `mysql_*` have been deprecated. So, try to use mysqli_* or PDO for querying.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table`(`this`) VALUES (`that`); INSERT INTO `table`(`this`) VALUES (`that`);");
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose you want 3 insertions simply do like this:

```
INSERT INTO outbox_multipart (TextDecoded) VALUES ('$SMSMessage'),('$SMSMessage'),('$SMSMessage');
```